# Can silverlight standalone be used to make a task server?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am in the planning stages for a task server development project.  I would like to be able to create a list of commands, and send that list to a process which will handle execution.  I would like it to be crossplatform (which probably means I must dip into java) but I would like to use C# if possible because I am familiar with it and the tools.

Can silverlight do the following

- Run as a background process that can talk to other processes (I know it can run standalone)?
- Do processor intensive tasks with similar efficiency as the .net run time?
- Be used to create a full featured desktop app like Excel, Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•Run as a background process that can talk to other processes (I know it can run standalone)?

No, Silverlight is "sandboxed" and has little or access to applications, memory or shared resources.

•Do processor intensive tasks with similar efficiency as the .net run time?

No, Silverlight uses a different CLR and has restrictions placed on memory size, threading etc.

•Be used to create a full featured desktop app like Excel, Word?

Not really although it can expose very similar functionality in a restricted form.

Comment: Even as a standalone (in fulltrust), it still is "sandboxed"?  I know I can start processes, and do a number of tasks that I couldn't do when it is just a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use ASP.NET? It's supported in other platforms too through the Mono framework: [ASP.NET - Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).
Silverlight is designed for client applications and it doesn't even allow server sockets, so creating a server is not possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm creating a custom server for a specific task and using existing web servers is not a good fit.  I would like to use silverlight to create the custom server if it can perform well and be multiplatform.

Comment: After some digging I found that you can't even create a listening socket with Silverlight, so creating a server is not possible.

Comment: thanks for digging. ok, I found some info on sockets too but it applies only to silverlight as a plugin.  Maybe as a standalone, it will be possible.  I will look more.  http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx